# Adding a function into a DOM element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call an function into my `<p>` which should call the numbers(while loop) 1 to 25. But I'm not sure how to move forward.

How would I append this info into the paragraph tag without using `console.log()` or `document.write()` but using instead `document.createElement` and `node.append` to insert my results into HTML?

How would I call this function inside a p tag in a DOM HTML?

```js
function oneThroughTwentyFive() {
  let count = 1
  while(count <= 25) {
    count++
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code ? Please provide a minimal working example!

Comment: on which event, and for which result ?

Comment: From my understanding, you want to display 1 in a p element, then increment it until you get to 25? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that it correct

Comment: Display where ?

Comment: i have vs code using my live server basically i have a <h2> that says Kata One and under that i want to display 1 to 25 inside the <p> tag

Comment: Ok but do you want the number to be replaced every time, so at the end you get `<p>25</p>`, or add a new number to the element, so it will look like `<p>1 2 3 4 5...` so on till 25

Comment: Yes correct adds a new number to look like <p> 1 2 3 4 .... until 25 correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will render a `<p>` element with the numbers 1 through 25 within it.

```html
<html>
  <body>

  </body>
  <script>
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = `
        let numbers = "";
        for (let e = 1; e <= 25; e++) numbers += e + " ";
        document.currentScript.parentNode.innerHTML = numbers;
    `
    p.appendChild(script)
    document.body.appendChild(p)
  </script>

</html>
```

Basically what this does is:

1. Create a `<p>` element
2. Create a `<script>` element
3. Add the Javascript code to display the numbers into the `<script>`
   element
4. Append the `<script>` element to the `<p>` element
5. Append the `<p>` element (which now has the Javascript code within it)
   to the body

And this is what the Javascript in the `<p>` element does:

1. Loop through all numbers from 1 to 25
2. Add each number plus a space (so the numbers won't be jammed up
   against each other) to the numbers variable
3. Find the parent element of the current script (in this case the `<p>`
   which contains the `<script>`
4. Overwrite the entire content of the `<p>` element (including the JS code used to create the numbers) with the numbers.

The Javascript code used to create the numbers is gone, so the final element will look like this:

```
<p>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

that ?

```js
const pTag = document.querySelector('p#pTag')

for (let i=1;i<=25;++i) pTag.textContent += i+' '


// -------------------------------------------

// the method name say's all
let otherP = document.createElement('p')  

// just a trick as many in JS
otherP.textContent = Array.from(Array(10),(_,i)=>i+25).join(' ') 

// append otherP in the right place on the DOM
document.body.appendChild( otherP )
```

```html
<p id="pTag"></p>
```

Comment: What if you had to use document.createElement() to create the <p> paragraph  and put that same code inside the paragraph element?

Comment: @WilliamElliot  added code for that. Please use MDN to learn everything about web dev, this place is not for learning languages, but for helping improvement coding techniques.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript